# How to join two tables and add a limit

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

Given two tables in a SQLite database,

app_vendor

```
app_id | vendor_id 
---------------
43     |  747
3      |  12
83     |  747

....
```

app

```
id | name
---------------
43 | Instagram
5  | Snapchat
```

and I am trying to get 10 'names' from 'app' (names of apps) for a given 'vendor_id'

```
SELECT A.name 
FROM app_vendor AS S 
WHERE vendor_id = 747 
JOIN app AS A ON S.app_id = A.id 
LIMIT 10
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For once, `WHERE` should be **after** `JOIN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause is in the wrong location. You can do:

```
SELECT A.name 
FROM app_vendor AS S 
JOIN app AS A ON S.app_id = A.id 
WHERE s.vendor_id = 747 
LIMIT 10
```

Result:

```
name      
--------- 
Instagram 
Snapchat
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kdhGcV1ZqZtanDkZu2X34U/0).

Answer (score 1):

Your `WHERE` clause is in the wrong place. I wouldn't join anyway, because all you want to do is select apps. Use a `WHERE` clause for the restriction.

```
select name 
from app
where id in
(
  select app_id
  from app_vendor
  where vendor_id = 747
  limit 10
);
```